# Lets-Encrypt Cert - Trust

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I installed git. For now, I installed self-signed certificates for accessing repos using https, but Visual Studio (on Windows 7) doesn't trust it easily (not without the manual step of saving it and adding it to trusted root certs). And it doesn't seem to work with SSH like most other tools. This may be a bit of an inconvenience for some users. Any ideas on how to get around this temporarily?

If I use lets-encrypt to replace my self-signed certs, will Visual Studio (on Windows 7 using https URLs) be able to trust it? Also, the server is temporarily internal and the domain name doesn't resolve to external users yet. So I am not totally sure lets-encrypt will work. What if we paid and obtained it from another CA, as a last option? Will it work then?

Can someone help me find this information?

Comment: Huh? What are you trying to do? Let's Encrypt only issues server certificates, not CA certificates. You need to describe your problem in more detail. Right now it's way too vague to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Ok sorry may be I should not have used the word CA. So if I use lets-encrypt certs in place of self-signed certs, will Visual Studio be able to access repos on my server?

Comment: I can't imagine any reason why it wouldn't be.

Comment: A site doesn't need to be publicly accessible to get a Let's Encrypt cert for it.  They have DNS-based domain control validation methods, and they work Just Fine.

Comment: The documentation says that the domain must be validated. See "Domain Validation": https://letsencrypt.org/how-it-works/ But our domain only resolves only internally (inside firewall).

Answer (score 2):

a cheap rapid ssl would be easiest if you don't have an existing pki and haven't exposed your site to the public.

Any Trusted cert will work, if you want to use letsencrypt you must re-sign every 90 days and must either expose your server publicly (you could put a dummy site on port 80 publicly that only is used for the cert generation) or via dns.  Any method will take up more than $9 of your time.

Comment: The question is not confusing _now_ after it's been edited.

Comment: Ok, thank you! RapidSSL is indeed cheap; may work well in my case.

Answer (score -2):

In technical terms, SSL security certificate are used to secure browsing communications, authentication and trust.

When you use self signed SSL certificate that will encrypt data but it is not qualified to provide authentication and trust. It can be suitable for testing environment. Self singed doesn’t recognize by browsers, therefore when users browse your website then they will experience security warnings.

CA signed certificate is the best solution for commercial purpose. You should choose trusted signed certificate for your website, certificate authority will verify your business authentication and provides strong encryption that can help to increase trust.

Comodo, RapidSSL, Symantec or any other CA signed certificates will work to secure your temporarily domain name. Below vendors offer CA singed certificate at free of cost for testing purpose.

https://www.freessl.com/freessl/good-karma/ - 30 days

https://www.geotrust.com/ssl/free-ssl-certificate/ - 30 days

https://www.instantssl.com/free-ssl-certificate.html - 90 days

https://www.ssl.com/certificates/free/ - 90 days